# Find all $2 \times 2$ matricies $B$ such that $B^{-1}=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know the identity matrix works for this, as well as any other value in the '$a$' and '$d$' spot of the matrix will work except zero. I'm stuck on the the '$b$' and '$c$' part of the matrix. Can that only be zero?

Comment: No.  $\pmatrix{ 2 & 0\\0 & 3} $ is not its own inverse.

Comment: are you asking for matrices with components from $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 4):

For a non-singular $2\times 2$ matrix we can solve the characteristic polynomial 
$$\eqalign{
0 &= B^2 -B\operatorname{tr}(B) + I\det(B) \\
B^{-1} &= \frac{I\operatorname{tr}(B)-B}{\det(B)} \\
}$$
Setting $B^{-1}=B$ yields
$$\eqalign{
B\det(B) &= I\operatorname{tr}(B)-B \\
B(\det(B)+1) &= I\operatorname{tr}(B) \\
}$$
So either ${\rm tr}(B)=0\;\underline {\rm and}\,\det(B)=-1,\;$ or else $B$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.

In the later case, assume $B=\beta I$
$$\eqalign{
\beta(\beta^2+1)I &= 2\beta I \\ 
\beta^3 - \beta &= 0 \implies \beta = \{0,\pm 1\} \\ 
}$$
Since $\beta=0$ is ruled out by the existence of $B^{-1}$, this yields two solutions $B=\pm I$.

For the remaining case, assume $\,B = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ 
$$\eqalign{
&{\rm tr}(B) = 0 &\implies 0=a+d &\implies d=-a \\
&\det(B) = -1 &\implies -1 = -a^2-bc &\implies b = \frac{1-a^2}{c} \\
&B = \pmatrix{a&\frac{1-a^2}{c}\\c&-a} \\
}$$
An interesting case occurs for $a=1$, then $b=0$ and $c$ can take any value.

Note that if $B$ is a solution, then $-B$ and $B^T$ are also solutions.

Comment: I rather enjoyed this approach. It incorporates some really nice matrix identities and getting your hands dirty with matrix algebra. There's a little bit for everyone.

Comment: did you mean $\det(B)=\color{red}-1$ in the penultimate line?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are absolutely correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently, $B^2 = I$, so the only eigenvalues are $-1$ and $1$.  Besides $I$ and $-I$, you can have a reflection: a matrix of the form $S \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & -1} S^{-1}$.  These can be written as 
$\pmatrix{a & b\cr c & -a}$ where $bc = 1 - a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\pmatrix{a&&b\\c&&d}=\pmatrix{a&&b\\c&&d}^{-1}=\dfrac{\pmatrix{d&&-c\\-b&&a}}{ad-bc}$,

then $a(ad-bc)=d,\tag1$

$d(ad-bc)=a,\tag2$

$c(ad-bc)=-c,\tag3$

and $b(ad-bc)=-b.\tag4$

From $(3)$ and $(4)$, $ad-bc=-1\tag5$ or $c=b=0.\tag6$

If $(5)$ holds, then from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $-a=d$;

if $b\ne0$, the matrix is $\pmatrix{a && b\\\frac{1-a^2}b && -a}$,

and if $b=0,$ then, from $(1)$, $a^2d=d,$

so either $a=d=0$, which can't be if the matrix is invertible,

or $a^2=1$, which means we have $\pmatrix{1&&0\\c&&-1}$  or $\pmatrix{-1&&0\\c&&1}$.

If $(6)$ holds, then, from $(1)$ and $(2),$ we have $a^2d=d$ and $d^2a=a$;

i.e., $(a^2-1)d=0$ and $(d^2-1)a=0.$

If $d=0$, then $a=0$, but then the (zero) matrix would not be invertible,

so it must be that $a^2=1$ and $d^2=1$; i.e., $a=\pm1$ and $d=\pm1;$

i.e., the matrix is $\pmatrix{\pm1&&0\\0&&\pm1}$.